# Unable to move file from ADLS to Snowflake

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-lake

I have my csv file in ADLS gen2. I need to upload this file into snowflake table.

I followed the [snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html).

My source data in ADLS :

[image]

Generated SAS token :

[image]

Tried loading with the SAS token in Snowflake environment :

```
copy into FACT.MOVIES
  from 'azure://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/airflow-dif/raw-area/'
  credentials=(azure_sas_token=''sp=r&st=2021-05-31T06:22:26Z&sx42021-05-31T14:22:26Z&spr=https&sv=2020-02-10&sr=c&sig=66z1SB1nxxxxxx2e0QGK4%3D'')
  file_format = (TYPE = CSV);
```

Getting the below error :

```
Failure using stage area. Cause: [This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. (Status Code: 403; Error Code: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch)]
```

Not sure what I am missing. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you're copying files from a virtual folder (`raw-area`), you will also need `List` permission in your SAS token. Currently you're only creating a SAS token with `Read` permission which does not allow you to list files.

Can you try by creating a SAS token with both `Read` and `List` permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be the credential you are using is wrong. credential is not sas token.

Comment: According the documentation here - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#examples, you can use sas token as credentials.